# Frame OutlineColor not work in only Android, Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, frame

I am developing the app in Xamarin Forms and I have faced a bug that should be fixed long time ago. 
I tried to set outline for frame and it works good on ios but doesn't work on android.

Here is my xaml for Frame.

```
<Frame
    HasShadow="true"
    CornerRadius="10"
    OutlineColor="Red"
    BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout 
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label
        Text="TEST"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label
        Text="For OUTLINE"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work for android. Bug is reported [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27460).

## Solution 1:

You should make a `Renderer` for the `Frame` for Android Platform as follows:

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using XFormsUI.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(RoundBorderFrameRenderer))]
namespace XFormsUI.Droid
{
    public class RoundBorderFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && e.OldElement == null)
            {
                SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.round_border_frame);

                //Write following lines if you want to bring the XAML Frame Elements's background Color into Native. Otherwise, Frame's BackgroundColor will not be effective.
                GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)Background;
                string FrameBackgroundColorHex = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(e.NewElement.BackgroundColor.R * 255), (int)(e.NewElement.BackgroundColor.G * 255), (int)(e.NewElement.BackgroundColor.B * 255));
                drawable.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(FrameBackgroundColorHex));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also requires an `xml` `(round_border_frame.xml)` selector file. Put this file in your `Drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--We need to give Frame's 'BorderColor Here-->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

## Solution 2:

Using `Renderer` without selector xml file. [Source](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/11/xamarin-form-frame-outline-color_21.html).

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using XFormsUI.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(RoundBorderFrameRenderer))]
namespace XFormsUI.Droid
{
    public class RoundBorderFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.Draw(canvas);

            using (var paint = new Paint { AntiAlias = true })
            using (var path = new Path())
            using (Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw)
            using (Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Stroke)
            using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height))
            {
                float px = Forms.Context.ToPixels(Element != null ? Element.CornerRadius : 10); //Default Corner Radius = 10
                float py = Forms.Context.ToPixels(Element != null ? Element.CornerRadius : 10); //Default Corner Radius = 10
                path.AddRoundRect(rect, px, py, direction);

                //Set the Width of the Border here
                paint.StrokeWidth = 1f;
                paint.SetStyle(style);

                //Take OutLineColor from XAML Frame element and set it natively here.
                string FrameBorderColorHex = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(Element.OutlineColor.R * 255), (int)(Element.OutlineColor.G * 255), (int)(Element.OutlineColor.B * 255));
                paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(FrameBorderColorHex);
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Solution 3:

However this is not the best solution but it's kind of a workaround:
Wrap your outer `Frame` inside another `Frame` having `Padding` and set its `BackgroundColor` to whatever your Border Color should be.

*Note:* I haven't checked this yet on iOS.

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="Red" CornerRadius="10" Padding="1,1,1,1">
    <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="TEST" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Text="For OUTLINE" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</Frame>
```

People are discussing this on this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70058/xamarin-forms-frame-outlinecolor-doesnt-work-on-android).

Hope this will help!!

Comment: hello, 
I tried solution 2 with binding OutlineColor

But seems that the StrokeWidth do nothing.
I can't get a bigger stroke. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Frame inside another frame worked for me. Thanks for the solution. Hoping Xamarin Team will fix this on android soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck around an half a day with this issue..

There my solution:

```
 using System;
 using Android.Content;
 using MyGlobe.Droid.Renderers;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
 using Android.Graphics;
 using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame),typeof(MyGlobe.Droid.Renderers.BorderFrameRenderer))]
 namespace Yours.Droid.Renderers
 {
 public class BorderFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
 {
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        using (var strokePaint = new Paint())
        using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height))
        {
            string FrameBorderColorHex = String.Format("#{3:X2}{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(Element.OutlineColor.R * 255), (int)(Element.OutlineColor.G * 255), (int)(Element.OutlineColor.B * 255), (int)(Element.OutlineColor.A * 255));

            // stroke
            strokePaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            strokePaint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(FrameBorderColorHex);
            strokePaint.StrokeWidth = 5;

            var radius = 10;

            canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, strokePaint);  // stroke
        }
    }

    public BorderFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
}
```