# Frame Outline Color did Not Work in Xamarin.Android

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to set a frame outline color for Android in **xamarin** forms?.Please Let Me Know If Anyone To know How To Solve this error.

Comment: Its a bug in older version of Xamarin Forms. Try upgrading Xamarin Forms to 3.0+.

Comment: Hi @AbsoluteSith but i am Using 3.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484760/frame-outlinecolor-not-work-in-only-android-xamarin-forms/47486895#47486895

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frame OutlineColor not work in only Android, Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484760/frame-outlinecolor-not-work-in-only-android-xamarin-forms)